# My script is working in jsFiddle but not in my browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to programming in general. I'm learning HTML/CSS/Javascript atm.

I created a simple script that allow the user to change the font size of the paragraph element.

I tired my code is jsFiddle and it works fine, but when I copied it into an HTML document and started the page. The HTML and CSS are functioning properly, but the problem is: JavaScript is not working. Btw I'm using Chrome as a browser.

**Is something wrong with my HTML document..? I'm so confused!**

Here is the working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o60gtvh8/

My HTML file (Download link / Dropbox): 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tl0npr5omefntv4/Font%20size%20changer.rar?dl=0

HTML file code ( Copy of the code in the HTML file provided in the download link above ):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1 {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 10px;
}

h2 {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 10px;
}

p {
  margin: 10px;
}

a {
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: cyan;
  color: black;
  padding: 3px;
}
</style>

<script>
function sizeChanger(size) {
  return function() {
    document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
  };
}
var size10 = sizeChanger(10);
var size20 = sizeChanger(20);
var size30 = sizeChanger(30);

document.getElementById('size-10px').onclick = size10;
document.getElementById('size-20px').onclick = size20;
document.getElementById('size-30px').onclick = size30;
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Tiger</h1>
<h2>(From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia)</h2>
<p>The tiger (Panthera tigris) is the largest cat species, most recognizable for
their pattern of dark vertical stripes on reddish-orange fur with a lighter underside.
The species is classified in the genus Panthera with the lion, leopard, jaguar, and snow leopard.
</p>
<a href="#" id="size-10px">Font size 10</a>
<a href="#" id="size-20px">Font size 20</a>
<a href="#" id="size-30px">Font size 30</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: checked the console (F12)?

Comment: JS needs to be on the end if you dont attach it to a `window.load`  event

Comment: the elements don't exist yet, because your script is declared before the elements. You would probably see an error stating the element wasn't found if you opened your console. Always make use of the console when things don't work as expected, it often highlights these kind of mistakes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your JavaScript to the end of the page before the closing body element. As it stands now you're trying to access elements that don't exist yet. jsFiddle works because by default they wrap the JavaScript code in a window.onload event.

```css
h1 {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 10px;
}

h2 {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 10px;
}

p {
  margin: 10px;
}

a {
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: cyan;
  color: black;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Tiger</h1>
<h2>(From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia)</h2>
<p>The tiger (Panthera tigris) is the largest cat species, most recognizable for
their pattern of dark vertical stripes on reddish-orange fur with a lighter underside.
The species is classified in the genus Panthera with the lion, leopard, jaguar, and snow leopard.
</p>
<a href="#" id="size-10px">Font size 10</a>
<a href="#" id="size-20px">Font size 20</a>
<a href="#" id="size-30px">Font size 30</a>


<script>
function sizeChanger(size) {
  return function() {
    document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
  };
}
var size10 = sizeChanger(10);
var size20 = sizeChanger(20);
var size30 = sizeChanger(30);

document.getElementById('size-10px').onclick = size10;
document.getElementById('size-20px').onclick = size20;
document.getElementById('size-30px').onclick = size30;
</script>
```

So there's nothing really wrong with your code (although you should avoid legacy DOM notation like `document.body.style.fontSize`) -- you're just executing it too early.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer!
Everything works fine now :)